SwiftUI: Updating a complex binding is not re-rendering a view correctly
For some reason, I have the odd view that won't update when a binding value changes. All of my views are generated via a for loop so theoretically, if one view was not working as intended then all of the views would be affected but this is not what is happening.
Here is a snippet of my view:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel
    
    
    
    init(viewModel: ContentViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            HStack() {
                VStack() {
                    main()
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func main() -> some View {
        if let component = viewModel.template, let components = component.components {
            List {
                ForEach(components, id: \.self) { item in
                    chapterContents(template: item, type: item.type, sectionId: component.id, subsectionId: nil, subsection: component)
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)  
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func chapterContents(template: Template, type: ViewKey, sectionId: String?, subsectionId: String?, subsection: Template) -> some View {
        switch type {
        case .checkbox: 
            if let data = template.data {
                    BinaryCheckBoxes(value: Binding<Bool>(get: {
                        return viewModel.formBinding[viewModel.sectionKey]?[sectionId ?? "MISSING"]?[template.id ?? "MISSING"] as? Bool ?? false
                    }, set: {
                        viewModel.formBinding[viewModel.sectionKey, default: [:]][sectionId ?? "MISSING", default: [:]][template.id ?? "MISSING"] = $0
                        viewModel.formResponse[viewModel.sectionKey, default: [:]][sectionId ?? "MISSING", default: [:]][template.id ?? "MISSING"] = $0
                    }), isEditing: $viewModel.isEditing)
            }
        }
}

struct BinaryCheckBoxes: View {
    
    @Binding var value: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Spacer()
            checkBox(text: "Yes", value: Binding<Bool>(get: {
                return value
            }, set: { _ in
                value = true
            }))
            
            Spacer()
            .frame(width: 40)
            
            checkBox(text: "No ", value: Binding<Bool>(get: {
                return !value
            }, set: { _ in
                value = false
            }))
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func checkBox(text: String, value: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        Toggle(isOn: value, label: {
            Text(text)
        })
        .toggleStyle(CheckboxToggleStyle())
    }
}


And here is a simplified version of the view model that controls the state of the view:
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var formResponse: [String: [String: [String:Any]]] = [:]
    @Published var formBinding: [String: [String: [String:Any]]] = [:]
    @Published var template: Template?
    @Published var sectionKey: String = "section1"
    @Published var isEditing: Bool = true
}



In the viewModel, template is constructed by decoding a Json file that details the layout of the view. This is because the view is dynamic.
The exact issue that is occuring with this setup is that tapping Yes does not update the view, so even though the formResponse and formBinding are being updated correctly to say true, the view still shows as false. This only happens though if the template doesn't have more than a couple of components in it. If I use a template that is longer then if the binaryCheck box won't update, but again only the odd one, not every view.
Have I missed something or do I fundimentally misunderstand how to use @Bindings/@Published?
Thanks for any help or advice.
=========================
Update:
debugging the code shows that the binding is being triggered, and reading/writing the correct value but the bit that isn't running is in CheckboxStyle, the overlay image is not changing based on the configuration.isOn. This should change when the binding value changes. but what is happening is the binding value changes but the overlay is not redrawn. Again this is only happening on a single binaryCheckboxView, so if my view had several binaryCheckBox views, all of them would work as intended except for one.
Here is the code for my checkboxStyle:
struct CheckboxToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Rectangle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                .overlay {
                    Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "checkmark" : "")
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        configuration.isOn.toggle()
                    }
                }
            
            configuration.label
        }
        
    }
}

=================
Update 2:
Here is an excerpt of the JSON and how I decode it to use as the UI template:
JSON:

[
    {
        "type": "subsection",
        "id": "subsection-1",
        "components": [
            {
                "type": "h1",
                "data": "Title",
                "alignment": "left"
            },
            {
                "type": "section",
                "id": "subsection-1-section-8",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "type": "h2",
                        "data": "Subtitle"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "checkboxes",
                        "id": "subsection-1-section-8-checkbox-1",
                        "data": "Yes|No"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "textentry",
                        "id": "subsection-1-section-8-textentry-1",
                        "data": "heading",
                        "lines": "5"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]



    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Array<Template>.self, from: data)

        continuation.resume(returning: decodedData)
    }
    catch {
        continuation.resume(throwing: error)
    }

Note that the actual json is use is much larger as it is used to generate the UI for the whole page.
=====================
Update 3:
After a little more debugging is seems the issue is to do with how many views are in the List. If I have "too many" views in the list then if the BinaryCheckBox is at the bottom then it will not correctly reload after being initially drawn, does anyone have any advice on how to deal with an issue like this?

StateObject instead of ObservedObject

Any can’t trigger a redraw

In the viewModel, template is constructed by decoding a Json file...
you are probably using JSONSerialization to get to your JSON data.
I suggest you try using JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseModel.self, from: data)
where the ResponseModel is a struct that matches your JSON data.
It is much easier to deal with, than the horrible [String: [String: [String:Any]]].
Copy and paste your JSON data into https://app.quicktype.io/ and the code is generated for you.

@workingdogsupportUkraine The template is constructed using JSONDecoder.decode(), with Template being what the JSON is decoded to. I use the dictionaries to store data that is written/read from the database. I use any as the root value because the cache stores several different types: String, Date, etc.

@JoakimDanielson Changing to a StateObject unfortunately does not make a difference.

can you show some representative sample of the JSON data you have, and how you decode it.

@workingdogsupportUkraine I have updated my question with a sample of the JSON and how I decode it.

Ok, I see what the Template could be now. In any case, I don't understand why you
are using the
horrible ... var formResponse: [String: [String: [String:Any]]] etc... instead of the
Template components and sub-components structs to do what you want, whatever that is.
Restructure your code, currently it is to brittle, like
return viewModel.formBinding[viewModel.sectionKey]?[sectionId ?? "MISSING"]?[template.id ?? "MISSING"] as? Bool ?? false then passing this to BinaryCheckBoxes
as binding, really?

it's best to learn the View struct is a view model
